# I want to write a regex in R to remove all words of a string containing numbers

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

For example:

```
x<-"Saint  A/74/PV.46 12/12/2019 4/66 19-40538 Lucia"
```

Should give me "Saint Lucia".

I tried

```
trimws(gsub("\\w*[0-9]+\\w*\\s*", "", x))
```

which gave me

```
Saint  A//PV.///-Lucia
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `gsub` to match letters, digits, from a word boundary (`\\b`) to the next, and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", gsub("\\b[A-Z/0-9.-]+\\b", "", x))
#[1] "Saint Lucia"
```

---

Or using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(str_extract_all(x, "(?<= |^)[[:alpha:]]+(?= |$)")[[1]], collapse = " ")
#[1] "Saint Lucia"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a replacing approach:

```r
x<-"Saint  A/74/PV.46 12/12/2019 4/66 19-40538 Lucia"
gsub("\\s*(?<!\\S)(?!\\p{L}+(?!\\S))\\S+", "", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "Saint Lucia"
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, "\\s*(?<!\\S)(?!\\p{L}+(?!\\S))\\S+", "")
## => [1] "Saint Lucia"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/eG0exO). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x77fol/2). Details:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?<!\S)` - start of string or a position immediately preceded with a whitespace
- `(?!\p{L}+(?!\S))`  - the next non-whitespace chunk cannot be a letter only word
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

Or, you may match all letter only words in between whitespace boundaries and join the matches with a space:

```r
paste(unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<!\\S)\\p{L}+(?!\\S)", x, perl=TRUE))), collapse=" ")
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/Fvm7o2). Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x77fol/1), it matches

- `(?<!\S)`  - a position at the start of string or right after a whitespace
- `\p{L}+` - one or more Unicode letters
- `(?!\S)` - immediately on the right, there must be a whitespace or end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gsub` to replace the characters starting from the first space(`" "`) to the last space with a single space.

```
x <- "Saint  A/74/PV.46 12/12/2019 4/66 19-40538 Lucia"
gsub(" .+ ", " ", x)
[1] "Saint Lucia"
```